# Chabad Chumash difference

Tags: product-recommendation, chabad, pentateuch-chumash, adult-learning

I try to understand the difference between two Chumash:

```
Kehot Chumash Synagogue Edition
Gutnick Chumash Synagogue Edition
```

What is the main difference and which one is recommended for use by Chabad Lubavitch? (Assuming that a person doesn’t know Hebrew yet)

Comment: http://www.lachumash.org/FAQs.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both translations attempt to weave the interpretation of rashi into the text so what you get is not a word-for-word translation of the hebrew text of the torah. Not to say that it's ideal to interpret the torah literally, but what you get is a watered-down, one-sided view of the torah and rashi's interpretation according to the   view of the translator which i consider to be a downside. The gutnick chumash has a box with explanations of different passages, terms, or ideas presented in the torah according to various commentators which i think is kind of cool. Both have a running commentary based on the writings of the lubavitcher rebbe. As mentioned in the other answer they're both pretty similar, but kehot is the official publishing house of chabad. If i had to pick one I'd probably pick the gutnick but i would honestly find a different chumash if you wanted a more accurate or less biased translation. Of course all translations are biased but in this case it's very obvious and so fundamental to the translation it's hard to work around.

Comment: Would you please say what translation is considered less biased and more accurate?

Comment: @romario artscroll, koren, jps

Comment: Translation that follows Rashi is biased? We've (all Jews) been learning basic Chumash with Rashi since 1475...

Comment: 0

Kehot Chumash is available online in different formats free of charge: https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/850580/jewish/Kehot-Chumash.htm

Comment: @user16403 Of course a translation that follows Rashi is biased against the other Rishonim (Ramban, Ibn Ezra, ......) and sometimes even Tannaim and Amoraim.

Comment: @user16403 yes it is biased against other interpretations and also i said it is not even al pi rashi but rather what the translator decides to include from rashi from the translator's viewpoint it does not replace learning actual rashi inside i find it very poor

Comment: @ezra generally in both examples being asked about the rashi's that are specific to grammar are left out but all of the other ones which can be written in a way to keep the text easier to read are included

Answer (score 2):

Kehot is the official publishing body of Chabad.

The Gutnick Chumash (published by kol Menachem) is made by rabbi Chaim miller who is a Lubavitcher.

Each one has its advantages and drawbacks. But overall I find they are relatively similar but that the kehot one does a better job at translating and helping to understand the basic Chumash. But the Gutnick one tends to be more popular.